# Remote Screen Viewing application

Tags: c#, client, screen, viewer

I am looking for a way to remotely share my screen with another computer, the main problem is that I need to integrate it into my current C# application. I have been doing research and was looking for someone who has already done this.

I am thinking from my research that I will need a piece of client software installed on the target machine to view the screen.

In theory I would like to view six separate screens from one computer and if possible have the ability to control the remote screen, just to verify I do not want to have a Remote Desktop like connection but a live view of the target computer.

Hoping someone can help.
Cheers,
Ben

Comment: It may be "too broad" for some, but it is exactly what I am looking for to at least get a foothold on where to start. Would love to know what resources you discovered that got you to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may need to implement piece of remote desktop in your code. There are plenty of resources addressed this problem some of them below.

http://bobcravens.com/2009/04/create-a-remote-desktop-viewer-using-c-and-wcf/

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43705/Remote-Desktop-using-C-NET

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311770/
```

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33979/Multi-RDP-Client-NET